# Acceder a controles dentro de un HUB Xaml y c#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Tengo un problemas al tratar de crear un formulario dentro de un Hub en un aplicacion UWP.

```
<Hub>
   <HubSection>
     <Datatemplate>
       <Grid>
         <TextBox x:Name="txtSerial"/>
       </Grid>
     </Datatemplate>
   </HubSection>
 </Hub>
```

El problema es que no puedo acceder al control `textbox` con el nombre para obtener su valor. He leído en alguna paginas que se podria user el evento `loaded` del control y un campo en la clase para hacerlo accesible, pero esto se me complicaría mucho ya que quiero crear varios formularios con varios campos cada uno. Si alguno puede ayudarme de antemano gracias.

Comment: Hola @EdwinV , has revisado este tema?

Comment: Hola @JuanK vi tus videos para entender mejor como trabaja el binding y el patron MVVM y lo estoy implementando en mis aplicacione aunque aun me queda mucho por aprender. Gracias JuanK por siempre responder mis preguntas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Así como lo tienes en todo momento puedes acceder al valor del control TextBox simplemente haciendo esto desde Code behind:

```
txtSerial.Text
```

Sin embargo es una mala práctica, si estas hasta ahora comenzando puede estar OK, pero mi recomendación es siempre usar MVVM y por ende no acceder nunca directamente al control, sino dejar que el binding se encargue de enlazar una propiedad de una clase (ViewModel) con una propiedad del control.

En resumen, te daré todo lo que necesitas , o buena parte. Lo primero es esta clase auxiliar , te ahorrará montones de trabajo luego:

#### [BindableBase](https://gist.github.com/JuanKRuiz/b686ca389077a120c60b)

```
using System.ComponentModel;
public class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool SetProperty<T>(ref T propertyBackStore, T newValue, 
                               [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (Equals(propertyBackStore, newValue))
            return false;

        propertyBackStore = newValue;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this,
                            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)
                            );

        return true;
    }
}
```

Una vez ya lo tienes debes crear un ViewModel, que para el ejemplo bastará con:

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _myStringProperty;
    public string MyStringProperty
    {
        get { return _myStringProperty; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _myStringProperty, value);}
    }
}
```

Luego desde tu code behind crea una instancia de este ViewModel, e inicializa sus valores en el evento `Load` así:

```
    public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    private void pageRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        ViewModel.MyStringProperty = "Asignado por binding";
        //No olvides asignar el ViewModel como DataContext 
        //Tambien se puede hacer por XAML y es más correcto
        //pero vamos de a poco
        DataContext = ViewModel;
    }
```

Ahora hay que modificar tu XAML

```
<Hub Loaded="pageRoot_Loaded">
   <HubSection>
     <Datatemplate>
       <Grid>
           <TextBox x:Name="txtSerial"  
                    Text="{Binding MyStringProperty}" />
       </Grid>
     </Datatemplate>
   </HubSection>
 </Hub>
```

Eso es todo, pero hay más ... bastante más... Si quieres por ejemplo que al cambiar el valor de TextBox cambie automáticamente el valor de la variable, puedes modificar el código así

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSerial"  
         Text="{Binding MyStringProperty , Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

EL binding no es tan complicado como parece, realmente te simplifica mucho la vida una vez te has habituado.

Para hacerte la vida más fácil te recomiendo revisar este artículo:

### [Apps, Binding, INotifyPropertyChanged y BindableBase | XAML | C#](https://juank.io/apps-binding-inotifypropertychanged-bindablebase-xaml-c/)

Y **te super recomiendo** este curso en video:

### [Tutorial de XAML](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcSxbpIm61W7YOZh8WLi-qRjTmjrBj5wE)

Especialmente los capítulos dedicados a binding: 5,7,8